# Getting all user ids/authors from Youtube video comments page

Tags: php, jquery, youtube-api

As the title says I want to get all the users ids who posted a comment on specific Youtube videos. I have looked all over for something like this, the Youtube data API comes close but I can only get it to pick up the comments and not the user it came from. The other method I've looked at doing is using greasemonkey + jquery to get them but jquery doesn't run on Youtube properly and alot of javascript functions don't either. Can anyone suggest a way this can be done?

Here is part of a script I was testing in greasemonkey:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('author')[1];
var mystring = elem.nextSibling;
var mynewString = mystring.innerHtml;

document.getElementById('google-cookie-alert').innerHTML = mynewString;
```

But it comes back undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. This will log out all the usernames for each of the commenters displayed.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("author");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if(elements[i].children.length > 0)
         console.log(elements[i].children[0].text)
}
```

Comment: Actually I have one more issue with this, It doesn't seem to do more than like 200 at a time, and after around 600 it does barely 15. This is but setting the max in the loop higher instead of elements.length but even with that it doesn't do all of them.

Comment: Youtube paginates its comments. You will also have to include a check whether or not the user exists like so `if(elements[i].children[0])` since deleted comments have no username child

Comment: Yeah I know I have to show more comments. So you think it's finding a deleted comment and then because that's empty it's getting an error?

Comment: Actually nevermind got it to work. It was because I was setting the lement.children part to a variable for use before the if check.